# GML axis order with EPSG-Code 31468 and 5678

Tags: epsg, gml

EPSG 31468 and 5678 basically mean the same: DHDN / 3-degree Gauss-Krueger zone 4. The difference is the axis order.

- EPSG 31468: northing-easting
- EPSG 5678:  easting-northing

In GML you can define a geometry with the following code

```
<gml:LineString srsName="EPSG:31468">
    <gml:coordinates>
        4552158.220450,5940320.204687
        4552155.166698,5940320.223569
    </gml:coordinates>
</gml:LineString>
```

My Question: When you change to srsName="EPSG:5678", is it necessary to swap the values in gml:coordinates?

```
<gml:LineString srsName="EPSG:5678">
    <gml:coordinates>
        5940320.204687,4552158.220450    ????
        5940320.223569,4552155.166698    ????
    </gml:coordinates>
</gml:LineString>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well yes, of course